# How to prove that Markov chain with specific transition probabilities has independent increments?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

I have Markov chain $N=\{N(t) \mid t\geq 0 \}$ with the state space $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. I know that it is homogeneous and transition probabilities are:
$$
 p_{ij}(s,t)=P(N(t)=j\mid N(s)=i) = p_{i,j}(t-s)\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{(\lambda (t-s))^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} e^{-\lambda (t-s)} & \quad j\geq i\\
 0 & \quad otherwise
 \end{array}
 \right.
 $$
and $p_i(0)=P(N(0)=i)=\delta_{i0}$.

How do I prove that this process has independent increments?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

$$P(N(t_1)=x_1,N(t_2)-N(t_1)=x_2,\dots,N(t_m)-N(t_{m-1})=x_m)=
P
\left( 
N(t_i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i x_j \text{ for } \forall i=1\dots m
\right) 
=P
\left( 
N(t_m)=x_1+\dots+x_m \mid N(t_i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i x_j ~ \forall ~ i=1\dots m-1
\right) 
P
\left( 
N(t_i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i x_j ~ \forall ~ i=1\dots m-1
\right) 
=[\text{Markov property}]=P(N(t_m)=x_1+\dots+x_m \mid N(t_{m-1})=x_1+\dots+x_{m-1})P
\left( 
N(t_i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i x_j ~ \forall i=1\dots m-1
\right) 
=p_{x_1+\dots +_{m-1},x_1+\dots+x_m}(t_{m-1},t_m)P
\left( 
N(t_i)=\sum_{j=1}^i x_j ~ \forall ~ i=1\dots m-1
\right) 
=[\text{repeat this procedure}]=p_{x_1,x_1+x_2}(t_1,t_2)p_{x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3}(t_2,t_3)\dots p_{x_1+\dots +_{m-1},x_1+\dots+x_m}(t_{m-1},t_m)P(N(t_1)=x_1)=
\left[ 
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{m-1} p_{\sum\limits_{k=1}^j x_k, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j+1} x_k}(t_j,t_{j+1})
\right]
P(N(t_1)=x_1)=
\left[ 
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{m-1} \frac{(\lambda(t_{j+1}-t_j))^{x_{j+1}}}{x_{j+1}!} e^{-\lambda(t_{j+1}-t_j)}
\right]
\frac{(\lambda t_1)^{x_1}}{x_1!} e^{-\lambda t_1}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^m P(N(t_i)-N(t_{i-1})=x_i)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You must show that $P(N(t)=i+j \mid N(s)=i) = P(N(t)-N(s)=j) \ \forall \ t,s \ge 0$

$P(N(t)=i+j \mid N(s) = i) = \cfrac{(\lambda(t-s))^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda(t-s)}$

$P(N(t)-N(s)=j) = P(N(t)=j+N(s)) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P(N(t)=j+i\mid N(s)=i)P(N(s)=i) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \cfrac{(\lambda(t-s))^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\cfrac{(\lambda s)^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda s} = \cfrac{(\lambda(t-s))^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda(t-s)} e^{-\lambda s}\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \cfrac{\lambda s^i}{i!} =  \cfrac{(\lambda(t-s))^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda(t-s)} \qquad \square$

Comment: What you showed is that $N(t)-N(s)\sim Pois(\lambda(t-s))$. Actually, my full problem is to show that $N(t)$ is a Poisson process, however I already showed that this fact is true as well as $N(0)=0$ almost surely, and now I only need to prove that $N(t)$ has independent increments. Or you are saying that independence of increments somehow easily follows from  $N(t)-N(s)\sim Pois(\lambda(t-s))$?

Comment: @Haldot What I proved is that the increment $N(t) - N(s)$ is independent of the non-overlapping increment $N(s) - N(0)$, by showing that $P(N(t)-N(s) = j \mid N(s) = i) = P(N(t)-N(s) = j)$. Note since $N(0) = 0, N(s)-N(0) = N(s)$

Comment: Ok, you're right, so we have that $P(N(s)-N(0)=n,N(t)-N(s)=k)=P(N(s)-N(0)=n)P(N(t)-N(s)=k).$ But don't we need this property for arbitrary finite family of increments, that is, $$P(N(t_1)-N(0)=k_1,N(t_2)-N(t_1)=k_2,N(t_3)-N(t_2)=k_3,\dots,N(t_m)-N(t_{m-1})=k_m )=P(N(t_1)-N(0)=k_1)P(N(t_2)-N(t_1)=k_2)P(N(t_3)-N(t_2)=k_3)\dots P(N(t_m)-N(t_{m-1})=k_m))$$ in order to have "process with independent increments"? I don't manage to see how to get this from the case with two increments

Comment: @Haldot Fair enough, I suppose I proved it for a special case $N(t)-N(s)$ and $N(s)-N(0)$. But all you need for a general case is $N(t)-N(s)$ and $N(s)-N(r)$, where $t,s,r \ge 0$, which should not be substantially different. Once you have shown $2$ general non-overlapping increments to be independent, I believe you can say all non-overlapping increments are independent. All you're really trying to show is that the value of $N(s)$ does not affect the distribution of $N(t)-N(s)$, and thus the Markov Property holds for the process

Comment: Wait, our process already is a Markov chain, it has Markov property by definition. And are you sure that it is enough to prove independence for $N(t)-N(s)$ and $N(s)-N(r)$ for $t>s>r\geq0$? If it's true, it would be super useful